# a provable upper bound on the summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following:

- an $(n \times z)$ matrix $A = {(a_1,a_2, ... ,a_n)}^{T}$ where $z \geq n$ and every $a_i$ is a $z$-dimensional row vector.
- $a_i = [a_{i1}  a_{i2} ...  a_{iz}]$ where $a_{ij} \geq 0 \forall j$
- $\sum_{i=1}^{z}a_{ri} = 1, \forall r \in ${$1,2,...,n$}.
- $\sum_{i=1}^{z}|a_{pi} - a_{qi}| \leq \epsilon, \forall p,q$ where $\epsilon << 1$.

Find a provable upper bound on:

- $\sum_{i,j=1}^{z}|(1/n)*\sum_{k=1}^{n}[a_{ki}.(a_{f(k)j} - a_{g(k)j})]|$

where f and g are permutations over the set {$1,2,...,n$} such that $f(i) \neq g(i) \forall i$.

I am expecting the bound to be $\epsilon^2$ but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Dear Manan, you already posted your question on math.stackexchange. I'm not sure there is an official policy about this yet, but doubling the effort of people who are doing this for free is not nice. You should have at least linked the other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/a-provable-upper-bound-on-the-summation

Comment: Moreover the question you posted looks a lot like homework, which is not the point of the present site. Hence I'm voting to close.

Comment: I am sorry for the repetition. Actually I am new at both these websites and I wasn't sure which was the correct website for it.
In future I'll definitely keep this in mind.
Thanks for pointing it out and sorry again.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Still, if you want it not to be closed, you should give some more information why you interested in this. As stated, the question looks like copied verbatim from a problem book, and homework is explicitly discouraged on this site.

Comment: Actually this came up during my research (albeit at a young stage) on Secure Communication that I am pursuing here at IIIT as a B.Tech + M.S. student.

I haven't copied this from anywhere. I just tried to frame my problem as formally as I could (as stated in FAQ).

The conditions that are given to hold come from the definition of secrecy from Mathew Franklin's Paper (http://www.springerlink.com/content/p0624333842u8120/).

To prove the solution to my problem I have to show that the expression (in the problem statement) is bounded by $\epsilon^2$.

Comment: Please let me know if more specifics or information is required. I just tried to define the problem such that no context of the original problem from where it came up is required to solve it.

Comment: Are the entries all positive?

Comment: @Daniel : Yes, they are. Thanks. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a copy-and-paste of the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/a-provable-upper-bound-on-the-summation/2380#2380) I posted to the same question on math.stackexchange.com so that the questioner can close this question.

The sum in question is at most ε<sup>2</sup>.  (We do not need the condition that the row sum equals 1 or the condition f(i)≠g(i) to obtain this.)

**Proof**.  Since
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j})=\sum_{k=1}^na_{f(k)j}-\sum_{k=1}^na_{g(k)j}=0,$$
we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}(a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j})\right|
=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{ki}-a_{1i})(a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j})\right|$$
$$\le\sum_{k=1}^n|a_{ki}-a_{1i}||a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j}|.$$
Therefore, the sum in question is at most
$$\frac1n\sum_{i,j=1}^z\sum_{k=1}^n|a_{ki}-a_{1i}||a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j}|
=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^z|a_{ki}-a_{1i}|\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^z|a_{f(k)j}-a_{g(k)j}|\right)$$
$$\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon^2=\epsilon^2.$$

Comment: But next time please do not post your question to more than one site at the same time.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I'll definitely keep that in mind in future.
Thanks again.